Manhwa Where Protagonist in a Subway and Fights Monsters
Description:
In this manhwa, a class of students is teleported to an underground subway system for a tutorial. The protagonist, who gains mysterious powers (i dont remember power), he tries to guide his colleagues by telling them to get on the subway train, which are filled with monster like creatures that spawn like a game, Then the system warns you that it is a mission to find the impostor/traitor. A guy with glasses, who has ice powers, starts harassing the protagonist’s crush, leading to a confrontation and the protagonist punches him in the face and makes him angry, shouting that he was going to kill the protagonist and throws ice spikes to try to pierce the protagonist but he stops the attempt and knocks out the guy with the glasses. After a fight, the guy with glasses wakes up and goes to the subway operator but when he gets there he becomes a monster (I don't remember how) and try attack everyone and protagonist fight and kill the guy.
And my memory ends there, I saw it two years ago but I don't remember where, he was completely colorful.

Does "he was completely colorful" mean that it, the manhwa, was completely in color?
